# Entity Framework 6: Clone object and relations except ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework

would you please tell me if I have some code like this :

```
using(var database = new MyDbContext()) {
MyModel myModel = database.Where(m => m.SomeProperty == someValue);
myModel.SomeOtherProperty = someOtherValue; //user changed a value
database.MyModels.Add(myModel); //even though the ID of myModel exists in the database, it gets added as a new row and the ID gets auto-incremented 
database.SaveChanges()
}
```

does it add the relationship Rows with new IDs ?

for Example if I have **tbl_order** and it has some childs in **tbl_order_details** , if I clone that by the code above , does it add tbl_order_details rows with new IDs ?

*I found this solution here : [Entity Framework 6: Clone object except ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id) **but here don't explain about the relations***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 6: Clone object except ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id)

Comment: I have question. What do you mean "MyModel is tbl_order" and "MyModels is tbl_order_details " ?

Comment: @LinhTuan I have a table called tbl_order and it has many to many relation with tbl_order_details

Comment: If you make same as above, it will never work :). And your question is not also correct

Comment: @LinhTuan really ? why? but this answer marked as solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id

Comment: You write your code same as above, right?

Comment: @LinhTuan yes, but I have replaced my classes !

Comment: If your question differs to that which it is suggested to be a duplicate of, please edit your question and clarify exactly how and why they differ. 

Duplicated questions will be closed, in which case you shall have to post a new and well-explained question; one that clarifies the aforementioned differences. Thank you.

Comment: You're asking one question. All this stuff about cloning only adds noise. The answer is: yes you can add objects *with* ID values as new objects.

Answer (score 0):

This code example for you:

```
public void CloneOrder(int orderId)
    {
        using (var database = new MyDbContext())
        {
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(m => m.Id == orderId);
            var newOrder = new Order{
                Content = order.Content
            }

            database.Orders.Add(newOrder);

            OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail{
                OrderId = newOrder.Id,
                Content = order.OrderDetails.Content
            };
            database.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
            database.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that the entity 6 do not add the relation rows automatically ?

Comment: @LinhTuan, it is very nice of you to try and answer the questions. However, please ensure that the question specifies the criteria you are implementing in your answer, or ask the person who is asking to edit the question and incorporate any such criteria. This practice ensures that others facing similar problem will be able to find the question and use your answer to their advantage. Also, avoid answering questions marked as duplicate, unless they have been clarified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example your new row will be added, the ONLY value that will be different from the original will be it's id column. If their were other columns that had foreign key relationships their values would be completely the same (not auto-incremented too). If you add one row then only one row will be added, there will be no creation of additional rows in the background. EF will not null foreign key values when cloning a row either (unless you tell it to)

Comment: you misunderstood my question, I want to clone data and add as a new record.