# Replicate Entire Row In Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am trying to retrieve a row from database , changing certain columns value in it and adding it as new row (Entity Framework Core),

But it is giving me error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Audit_Schedules' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

This table have a Primary Key **"ScheduleId"**

Below is my Code

```
 AuditSchedules _schedules = new AuditSchedules();
 using (var ctx = new QuestionnaireEntities(_configuration))
                {
                    _schedules = ctx.AuditSchedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleId == model.ScheduleID).SingleOrDefault();
                    _schedules.StaffId = model.TransferedAuditorCode;
                    _schedules.StaffName = model.TransferedAuditorName;
                    _schedules.FromDate = _schedules.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.TransferedScheduleDate);
                    ctx.AuditSchedules.Add(_schedules);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    _subschedules = ctx.AuditSubSchedule.Where(x => x.SubScheduleId == model.SubScheduleID).SingleOrDefault();
                    _subschedules.IsHoliDay = "Y";
                    _subschedules.HolidayType = model.HolidayType;
                    _subschedules.TransferedScheduleId = _schedules.ScheduleId.ToString();
                    ctx.AuditSubSchedule.Update(_subschedules);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Error Comes In

```
ctx.AuditSchedules.Add(_schedules);
```

First I thought its conflicting in value of Schedule_ID and not able to add duplicate Primary Key , But Schedule_ID is auto generated field so this issue should not occur

I also tried setting it to different value

```
_schedules.ScheduleId = 0;
```

but it does not insert . 
How Can I replicate a row with few changes in it (want to add a new row but modified values)

Comment: Much cleaner to make a new object  and copy a few more fields. Also, your SingleOrDefault() should become just Single() .

Comment: The error is clear enough, you need to clear out the PK of both tables.

Comment: You didn't tell EF that `ScheduleId` is an identity column so it tries to insert a value into it.

Comment: @GertArnold , Than how SQL generate value of it when we use Add() Method ,

Comment: You know what an identity column is, do you? Any insert generates a next value. `Schedule_ID` shouldn't be in the insert statement EF generates, that's the point.

Comment: @GertArnold , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id , its an old post but solve the same problem , neither he or me touching the Primary Key field . Funny thing is it does not work in my case

Comment: The difference is that in your case EF doesn't know that the column is an identity column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF Core behavior with auto generated values on insert is different than EF6.

First, the property must have default value (`0`) in order to be auto generated. This allows identity inserts which was not possible in EF6.

Second, the entity being added should not be already tracked by the context, because otherwise the context keeps internally some information that the entity key has been set and will include the value (even `0`) in the generated `INSERT` command, which in turn causes the exception you are getting.

To achieve the goal, *before* calling the `Add` method:

First make sure the entity is not tracked by either using [No-tracking query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries) when obtaining it

```
_schedules = ctx.AuditSchedules
    .AsNoTracking() // <--
    .Where(x => x.ScheduleId == model.ScheduleID)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

or explicitly detaching it

```
ctx.Entry(_schedules).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Then reset the PK

```
_schedules.ScheduleId = 0;
```

The do other modifications and finally call

```
ctx.AuditSchedules.Add(_schedules);
```

This will work for simple entities w/o navigation properties / FKs. For complex entity graph you should use no tracking query, and then work with it the same way as with detached entity graphs.

Comment: AsNoTracking()  does not come in intellisence

Comment: Then you need `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` (many EF Core methods are provided via extension methods)

Comment: I get this working by using `UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` on the Id property, using `AsNoTracking` and setting the id value of the added object to 0. When you mention that the property needs a default value, do you mean it must be a (CLR) datatype having a non-null default? In my test, `HasDefaultValue(0)` wasn't required (and redundant). BTW nice to know of yet another area where EF-core differs from EF6. This may be very useful in replication to other databases. Now it can be done without having to tamper with the mappings.

Comment: Hi @Gert I was assuming the property is already identity column, otherwise OP won't get that exception. And yes, I meant setting the auto generated property of the object to the CLR `default` value. The main difference with EF6 is that EF6 always ignores the current value of the identity column of the entity marked as `Added` as you know, while EF Core respects it. Indeed this allows identity inserts w/o changing the mappings :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple, it is because you are adding the identity insert as a part of insert. If it is identity, it has to be auto generated. So either turn off before insert and then turn it on. Or make it auto generated.

This error will be the same if you try and insert the same data from sql server.
This is basically propagated from sql server.

If you do not want an ID to be database generated, then you should use the DatabaseGenerated attribute on your model, as in

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ScheduleId {get;set;}
```

If you want the identity insert to be off you can try the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896047/how-to-turn-on-identity-insert-in-net-core)

Comment: I do not want to set it off , I want to add it as new record with new identity value in table

Comment: like in Add() method , we need not to supply value of this field , SQL auto generate it

Comment: If you dont want to set it off, let sql handle it.