# Copy one array to another array except one property in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an array of objects.
I want to copy this array of objects into another array, except one property of the first array which is an identity column. How do I do that ?

```
public class Lot
{
    [Key]
    public int LotNumber { get; set; }
    public string LotName { get; set; }
}

Lot[] ExistingLots = (from l in _context.Lot.Where(c => c.NumLot == 999).Select l).ToArray();
int size = ExistingLots.Length;
Compteur[] DestinationLots = new Compteur[size];
```

//Copy all but the LotNumber

```
Array.Copy(ExistingLots , 1, DestinationLots , 1, CompteursExistants.Length-size);
```

Comment: Do you want to copy it over with that value as `null`, or without that property altogether? The latter would require either another model.

Comment: That is a wierd requirement. Usually the Key is the *last thing* you should ever want to get rid off. If there was only one value I could transmit, the PK would be my first choice. If I have to invent a ID for the UI side/ASP.NEt page, the PK is always my first choice.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I don't want to transmit that property as it is an identity column. I would like to 'remove' that column when copying

Comment: You need to seriously update this question with precisely what you want.  Start with what you have in an example, and then show what you want the code to do, then show your code.  We don't know what Compteur or any other classes you've specificed.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for the info. The primary key is an identity column. Basically I want to copy n rows of a table to another n rows, except the identity column

Comment: @TropicalViking you want to insert rows from one table to another? Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes, entity framework, but copying / inserting into the same table.

Comment: @RufusL The value gets generated automatically on insert. It is an Identity Column

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Then just select a new `Lot` and don't set a value for that property.

Comment: @RufusL This is a simple class I've taken for the example, but in real my class has 30 fields and I want to copy all except IdLot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework 6: Clone object except ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720803/entity-framework-6-clone-object-except-id)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks man ! Let me test this out. It looks like it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create new `Lot` objects using your existing values, then add these back into your `DbSet`:

```
Lot[] destinationLots = ExistingLots
    .Select(el => new Lot { LotName = el.LotName })
    .ToArray();
_context.Lot.Add(destinationLots);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Johnnathan Barclay   Let me check this one out ! thanks

Comment: This is a simple class I've taken for the example, but in real my class has 30 fields and I want to copy all except IdLot. How to do that ?

Comment: @TropicalViking Exactly the same way, just add the other properties. `new Lot { Property1 = el.Property1, Property2 = el.Property2 }`

Comment: @TropicalViking actually I didn't realise this, but you can just add the existing entities back into your context and EF will add them as new rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722197/8126362

Answer (score 0):

I decorate the LotNumber with Identity and it now works. I had removed it because of a data import where the column values needed to be kept.
Thanks all !

```
  public class Lot
  {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int LotNumber { get; set; }
        public string LotName { get; set; }
   }
```